# How to create a function returning the next list element after it is called in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a function (read-line), which asks the user for an input, but i want to write a test, where i determine, what the user uses as input.

I would need a function, that returns 1, when called and 5, when called a second time and so on. Basically, i have a vector of numbers and the next one should be called, when the function is called. How is this possible and what is the clojure way?

vector is [1 5 3]

```
(myfunction) => 1
(myfunction) => 5
(myfunction) => 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `my-function` in [`let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let) with some [`atom`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/atom) and modify that value.

First option: you'll create `atom` with that vector and call `first` and `rest`, something like this:

```
(let [values (atom [1 5 3])]
  (defn my-function []
    (let [e (first @values)]
      (swap! values rest)
      e)))
```

Second option: you'll use `atom` with index and increase that index:

```
(let [values [1 5 3]
      i (atom -1)]
  (defn my-function []
    (get values (swap! i inc))))
```

Test for both options:

```
(my-function)
=> 1

(my-function)
=> 5

(my-function)
=> 3

(my-function)
=> nil
```

If you want to return to the first element after the third one, you can use [`cycle`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cycle) or [`mod`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mod):

```
(let [values (atom (cycle [1 5 3]))]
  (defn my-function []
    (let [e (first @values)]
      (swap! values rest)
      e)))

(let [values [1 5 3]
      i (atom -1)]
  (defn my-function []
    (values (mod (swap! i inc) 3))))
```

By the way, this solution (using `defn` inside `let`) is possible due to something called [*lexical closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))- in short: the function "remembers" the environment, where it was created, and it can reference variables from that environment.

Answer (score 2):

you can also employ the java iterator for that, since clojure collections implement [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)

```
user> (def it (.iterator [1 2 3]))

user> (when (.hasNext it) (.next it))
;;=> 1

user> (when (.hasNext it) (.next it))
;;=> 2

user> (when (.hasNext it) (.next it))
;;=> 3

user> (when (.hasNext it) (.next it))
;;=> nil
```

or abstracting it to function:

```
(defn iter [data]
  (let [it (.iterator (sequence data))]
    #(when (.hasNext it) (.next it))))
```

(notice, i use 'sequence' on data to prevent NPE when `nil` is passed)

```
user> (def next-item (iter [10 20 30]))

user> (next-item)
10
user> (next-item)
20
user> (next-item)
30
user> (next-item)
nil


user> (def next-item (iter nil))

user> (next-item)
nil
user> (next-item)
nil
```